# React array not modified when changed in a timer callback function

Tags: reactjs, react-state

The following code displays a list of items.  The list is held in a state variable `list`.  There are two ways to add items to the list: either manually by clicking the Inc button, or by starting the timer which adds an item to the list every 1 second.

The Inc button works but the timer function does not.  When examining the timer function, the state variable `list` does not appear to persist its new length between calls.

Why is this?  Thank you for reading.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export function Tester() {

    const [list, setList] = useState([]);

    var timer = null;


    function startTimer() {

        // Start a timer
        if (timer == null)
            timer = setTimeout(timeoutCallback, 1000);

    }

    function timeoutCallback() {

        //
        timer = null;

        //
        btnClicked();

        //
        startTimer();

    }

    function btnClicked() {

        let today = new Date();
        let strTime = today.getHours() + ':' + today.getMinutes() + ':' + today.getSeconds();

        setList([
            ...list,
            {
                name: "item " + strTime,
                id: list.length + 1
            }
        ]);

    }


    const renderedItems = list.map(
        X => {
            return <span key={X.id}>{X.id}+{X.name} </span>
        }
    );

    return (
        <>TESTER
            <button onClick={startTimer}>Timer</button>         
            <button onClick={btnClicked}>Inc</button>
            {renderedItems}
        </>
    );

}
```

Comment: stale closures..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a callback to `setList` that takes the previous state value of the list and computes a new value, as the value of `list` will be stale.

```js
      setList((prevList) => [
          ...prevList,
          {
              name: "item " + strTime,
              id: prevList.length + 1
          }
      ]);
```

In addition, you need to use [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) to persist the instance of the timer between renders without triggering new rerenders when the current value of `timer` changes.

```js
  const timer = useRef(null);


  function startTimer() {

      // Start a timer
      if (timer.current == null)
          timer.current = setTimeout(timeoutCallback, 1000);

  }

  function timeoutCallback() {

      //
      timer.current = null;

      //
      btnClicked();

      //
      startTimer();

  }
```